# How do Star Trek transporters stop you from being merged with stuff?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-transporter

In *The Wrath of Khan*, Chekov beams down to a planet with a raging sandstorm. How do the transporters stop the sand from being inside him as he materialises?

Comment: It doesn't stop it happening completely, there was a Voyager episode where Neelix and Tuvok got merged into one

Comment: For the record, this is not a duplicate question, and those other threads are incorrect. The correct answer is... the pattern buffer (which you hear about in many shows) is what prevents the crew from being merged with other objects. When a crew member beams somewhere their pattern is stored in the pattern buffer. When they beam back only the original pattern is used. Accidents only happen when the buffer fails (as clearly stated in those episodes).